# Can't switch to a specific system account with su

Tags: su

I can't switch to user jenkins on an OpenVZ container.
There is still a jenkins process running, which was started by this user.

I tried `# su jenkins`; it does not switch to the jenkins user. There is no error message.

`/etc/groups` shows there is a jenkins group: `jenkins:x:498:`. I tried `id -g jenkins` and got this: `jenkins(uid=497)`. There is a `/etc/passwd` entry:

```
jenkins:x:497:498:Jenkins Continuous Build server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false
```

Nothing happened to this container. I revisited it some time after it was stopped, I started it and found it in this situation.

So there is a jenkins user. Why can't I switch to it?

Comment: Does `/etc/passwd` show an entry for user jenkins? Did anything happen that could have caused this user account to be deleted? Do you get any error messages when you run the `su` command that you posted?

Comment: This is /etc/passwd entry `jenkins:x:497:498:Jenkins Continuous Build server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false` There is no error if I try to switch using su jenkins, Nothing happened to this container I revisited after some time it was stooped i started it and found in this stituation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason `su jenkins` appears to fail is because the user's shell is `/bin/false`. You can specify a shell with `su` that will be used instead of the default login shell:

```
su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Comment: The standard does not mention a `-s` option for `su` and on FreeBSD, `-s` sets the MAC security label...

Comment: Downvoting this, as this didn't worked for me in Ubuntu.

Comment: @eigenfield My answer assumed the user was already root as indicated in the question. That is why you needed `sudo`.

Comment: Feature idea? "su" could make an observation like "Hello root, you're using /bin/bash but (user) is using /bin/false -- How would you like to proceed?"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash >username<;
```

Comment: Upvoting this, as this worked for me in Ubuntu.